# jQuery click() not working on Google +1 Button

Tags: jquery, google-plus, google-plus-one

This page (http://buttonspace.com) is using the Google +1 button at the top.

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/

It was working fine until about 2 months ago, when I'm assuming Google updated the code for their button.

Any ideas why this jQuery click() code isn't firing?

```
<script>
    $("#g-plusone").click(function(){
        console.log("Clicked!");
        alert("Clicked!");              
    });
</script>
```

Comment: At a guess, google has updated its functionality to catch the click event and `evt.preventDefault()` and `evt.stopPropagation()` -- it seems the click event simply isn't getting passed back out of the innermost element. Test this by listening for the hover event on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have the selector wrong. I'm seeing it as `.google-plus-one` on a LI element. Or, there's also a DIV inside it with ID `#___plusone_0`
, maybe that's what you're looking for.

[image]

Try it like this:

```
<script>
    $(".google-plus-one").click(function(){
        console.log("Clicked!");
        alert("Clicked!");              
    });
</script>
```

Though then you'd be attaching the event to the LI (or DIV) containing the Iframe with the button, not the button itself. And you won't be able to get to the button inside the Iframe because of the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do anything either :(

Comment: If I click barely outside the button it works, but not on the actual button itself. So I'm guessing the "Same Origin Policy" means there's no way to get it to work?

Comment: Unfortunately you can only access iframe's elements if the iframe' `src` is in the same domain.

Comment: So are you saying there's no way (either with javascript, jQuery, HTML, etc) to capture a click on that button?

Comment: Looking around the internet, I found there used to be a `data-callback` and an `onClick` parameter on the button, but now I can't find it in the docs. So they probably removed it :(.

Comment: You are correct @ishegg! The data-callback used to work, but it stopped working, so I'm trying another method. I just want *anything* that can track a click on that button. I'm surprised it's so difficult lol.

Comment: What I think you should do is make your own button with the JS API, and then when a user clicks you trigger the +1 AND a custom function. Looks there's no more options.

Comment: That's pretty clever! I'll see what I can do, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something along the lines of:

```
$("body").contents().find(".google-plus-one").click()
```

to find the content inside the iframe and do something to it. What you were doing before would require the markup to be on the page initially in order to bind your event to the element. You need a way to do select the element after its rendered to the DOM.

Comment: I tried this, no luck. Maybe it has to do with the "Same Origin Policy" issue that another answer mentioned?

Comment: have you tried making it an ON so it doesnt have to bind before it load on the DOM? something like $('body').on('click', '.google-plus-one', function () {
     console.log("here");
});

Comment: I had to upgrade jquery from 1.4.1 to 3.2.1 because the "on" function wasn't available. But alas it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

So my workaround solution is to use an image to represent the button, then a hyperlink that opens the new window for the G+ post. By bypassing Google's API and iframe, I'm able capture the click event.

```
<li class="google-plus-one">                
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?app=110&url=<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="/google_plus.png" alt="Google +1"></a>
</li>

<script>
    $(".google-plus-one").click(function(){     
        console.log("clicked!");                
    });
</script>
```